# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when running docker in localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize my node application but cannot serve to my localhost. I keep getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on the page and it's immediate. The strangest part is that I can occasionally go back or forward in my browser to the page and get the page. The application will run correctly, except for the web sockets, which also have the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: client/client.Dockerfile
    image: client:1.0
    container_name: client-dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - server
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server/server.Dockerfile
    image: server:1.0
    container_name: server-dev
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    command: npm start
```

My dockerfiles:
Server:

```
FROM node:9.10.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/
COPY ./server/package.json ./server/package.json
WORKDIR /usr/src/server
RUN npm install
COPY ./server .
EXPOSE 8081
```

Client:

```
FROM node:9.10.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/
COPY ./client/package.json ./client/package.json
WORKDIR /usr/src/client
RUN npm install
COPY ./client .
EXPOSE 8080
```

I've looked into this a decent amount and found that this issue usually comes from not publishing the port for use, but from what I can tell, I've done that. At a minimum, I was able to access the app through odd means so I'm pretty sure I've done it correctly. I think being able to back up into the page may have been caused by browser caching since I can't replicate it after I've cleared my cache.

At some point, I thought that the issue might come from cors problems since the docker container runs from a different IP than the host machine, but whitelisting my own IP didn't change the issue.

Additional notes:

I have morgan on my server and it was logging requests when I was able to get onto the page, but not when I try to access localhost:8080 through normal means.

I have tried `docker system prune -a` to clear everything out and avoid caching issues.

I have tried client-side solutions to `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` errors and they didn't change anything.

At this point I'm just throwing stuff at the wall in the hopes that anything makes an impact.

Comment: The other frequent cause of this is a process set to listen only on the localhost interface; if it prints something like "listening on 127.0.0.1:3000" at startup, it will not be reachable from outside the container no matter what you do.  Set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 in code or configuration as appropriate.

Comment: The list of containers when I use `docker container ps` shows the port is 0.0.0.0:8080. From what I've read that means that it should be accessible. Also I was able to reach it in that odd instance of backing up into it on my browser, so I'm under the impression that it's in some way reachable.

Comment: The `docker logs` output will be more informative.  You can set any `ports:` you want but they won't actually work if the process inside the container isn't listening in the right place.